# Trouble with setting custom controller redirect for devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble setting Devise properly with my controllers. I've tried quite some things but nothing seems to work. Please do not redirect me to the wiki, i know about it, have tried things without success.

In my current situation, after login the user is redirected properly, but after sign up, it seems that current_user is not available.

So, my question is :

If i have a controller named Town, how can i redirect devise to that controller after successful login and successful signup ?

EDIT :

there seems to be some kind of messing with the controllers. Some times, i get errors like :

```
No route matches {:action=>"monster_attack", :controller=>"user/tavern"}
```

although user/tavern is never specified, when i login sometimes, i get that redirection. If i specify it like :controller => '/tavern', it works ok. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well normally the following works for me. Given you are in Rails 3 you are working with a Devise Model called "User", you could do something like this in your routes.rb file:

```
devise_for :users
namespace :user do
  root :to => "town#show"
end
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: i actually already have that in my routes, but still, i get an error in signup. The error is NoMethodError, gettting nil out of current_user, that is.